# HP Pavilion G6 overheating due to the graphics driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, hp, overheating

I have an HP Pavilion G6 where I recently installed Ubuntu instead of Windows 7 on it

I googled a bit and found out that the problem to my overheating was the graphics accelerator which was "FGLRX graphics driver (**experimental** beta", I tried removing it but failed to do because I have no ati folder in /user/share/

I'm only trying to remove it and install a more stable one but failing to do so too

Are there any solution to this?

My CPU is at 106 degrees celcius

Answer (score 0):

You can try deactivate the graphic driver in 'additional drivers'.